# Grails - gorm false OR NULL

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a field in a table called disabled that is a Boolean. I'm trying to query for both false or null but can't seem to get it to work. I have tried a few things, most likely solution but didn't seem to work is

```
p = book.createCriteria().list {
'in'('createdUnderAccountCustomerNumber', accountIds)
and {
   'in'('createdUnderProfessionalCustomerNumber', professionalCustomerNums)
   isNull('disabled')
   or {
     eq('disabled', false)
   }
}
```

Basically I want get all the books created under a list of accounts and a list of professionals which has disabled set to either false or null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the two parts of the `or` inside the closure:

```
or {
    isNull('disabled')
    eq('disabled', false)
}
```

Comment: Geeeez, spent over an hour trying out different forms. THANKS!